# Explanation for Homogeneous Nucleation Temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

What is homogeneous nucleation temperature (for water this is listed as -42C); is it simply the lowest experimental temperature you can go before supercooled liquid turns into solid, or is it that supercooled liquid doesn’t turn into solid until you go below that temperature (i.e. supercooled water at -30C will never freeze)? If it is the latter then I am confused as to what physically can prevent water from turning inte at positive subcooling?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reaching the homogeneous nucliation temperature, thermal vibrations are sufficient to induce the phase change. Above, stronger perturbations are needed.

Comment: So homogeneous nucleation temperature is the lowest possible temperature that a liquid can exist (at some pressure), but it does not preclude the possibility of a liquid-solid transition above it?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.